# Spring Boot: Data access depending on role

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

For my REST-API within a data-warehouse I need some role-based data access. First lets clarify the requirements with some small example. We define to entities `Author` and `Book`, both use the `PagingAndSortingRepository` for their default behaviour. An author can "own" several books, where an book can only depend to one author.

The simplified entities should look like the following:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author{
    // [..]
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book{
    // [..]
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Author_ID")
    private Author author;
}
```

Then I define two roles `User` and `Admin`. Normally an author is a common user, so the authorization mechanise only adds a `SimpleGrantedAuthority` for the role `User`. But there are some special authors which additionally have the role `Admin`.

When a normal author with role `User` calls the url `\books`, he should only get the books he own, while an an author with role `Admin` should get all books that exist. Also for the `PUT/PATCH/DELETE` request authors with the `User` role, should only be able to update / delete their own books, while the `Admin` role is able to do this for all books.

**My Question:** Is there a way to define the data access **once** in the `Controller` class? I know something like that from the `Django-Framework`, where I can override the method `get_queryset()`, which provides the dataset to work with for every "view"-method (GET/LIST/CREATE/UPDATE/etc.). The way I currently archive this, is to define the methods in the controller for the different API-endpoints and than mange the access there. Which causes two problems:

- A lot of work, to implement the methods in the controller
- If you have many dependencies between your entities, which is the case for my dwh, you can **easily miss some endpoint**. As result, I might have an endpoint, where every author has full access, no matter which role.

I thinks this should be a common problem, but I couldn't find a common solution yet. So I am thankful for every advice.

---

**Edit:** Example of "secured method"

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dimensionAttributeValues", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public PagedResources<DimensionAttributeValue> getDimensionAttributeValues(Pageable pageable, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler) {
        Page<DimensionAttributeValue> result;

        if (SecurityUtils.userHasRole(ADMIN) || SecurityUtils.userHasRole(TIMEMANAGER)) {
            result = dimensionAttributeValueService.getAllDimensionAttributeValue(pageable);
        } else {
            result = dimensionAttributeValueService.getUserDimensionAttributeValue(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName(), pageable);
        }

        PagedResources<DimensionAttributeValue> resources;
        resources = this.toResource(result, persistentEntityResourceAssembler);

        // TODO: Remove dirty Hack!
        Link searchLink = linkTo(DimensionAttributeValueController.class).slash("/dimensionAttributeValues/search").withRel("search");
        resources.add(searchLink);

        return resources;
    }
```

Comment: Are you already using Spring Security?

Comment: Yes I do that for authentication and to hide all endpoint from non-authenticated users.

Comment: You could try something like: `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` on your controller.

Comment: @Sebastian I have added some example how I currently do it

Comment: @Sebastian this works only if don't need to server different data depending on the role, see the added example.

Comment: Maybe this is something you can use: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-role-filter-json

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it at repository level, spring security gives you access to the principal in the repo.

You need anyway to define a custom query for that.

Something similar to what described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-security in chapter 3.2

Otherwise you can add Service layer and than use the `@PreAuthorize` annotation

Comment: If I understood the example correctly, than I need to define the query for every endpoint. Which is hard if have to serve different data depending on the role

Answer (score 0):

You could add a where condition to your repository call to filter the result by roles.
Therefor check this method of the JpaSpecificationExecutor:

```
Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> var1, Pageable var2);
```

Example (Can't test it right now, but this should lead you in the right direction) :

```
import static org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specifications.where;
..
Specification<Book> roleFilter = (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("role"), "Admin");

Page<Book> page = this.yourRepository.findAll(where(roleFilter), pageable);
```